# What does Format$ with argument "00" do in VB6?

Tags: vb6

I am looking at VB6 with statements like -

```
  selected = lstIDS.ListIndex
  NUM_ENTRIES = Format$(selected, "00")
```

What does the format function with the "00" argument do?

Comment: makes "1" look like "01", for example. Prepends `0` to a 1-digit number

Comment: It isn't nice to make an answer a comment! :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Format$(1, "00")` returns `01`. `Format$(1, "000")` would return `001` and so on. That format argument specifies the minimal numer of digits the number will be displayed with. There, I did it :-)

Comment: +1. The numeric formatting specifiers are described in the manual http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263416(v=vs.60).aspx